# insert failed using php mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I create a form-based registers oop. But when I press the button, the data is not stored. and there is no error information at all.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo $message; ?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <form action="register.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Username:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Username.">
                                <p class="help-block">Ex. oimtrust</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Password.">
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Nama Lengkap:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Fullname.">
                                <p class="help-block">Ex. Fathur Rohim</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Jenis Kelamin:</label>
                                <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Pilih Gender</option>
                                    <option value="Pria">Pria</option>
                                    <option value="Wanita">Wanita</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Nomor Telepon:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Phone.">
                                <p class="help-block">Ex. 08133304****</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Alamat:</label>
                                <textarea name="address" rows="3" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Address.">                                   
                                </textarea>
                                <p class="help-block">Ex. Jl. Supriadi RT:03, RW:04</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_role" value="3">
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control">Register</button>
                                <p class="help-block">Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Sign in here</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

the code above is the html code. The following code to insert the data.

```html
<?php
 $message = "";

 session_start();
 //Jika sudah login
 if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header('location:index-owner.php');
  exit();
 }

 //Jika belum login
 if (!empty($POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $fullname  = $_POST['fullname'];
  $gender  = $_POST['gender'];
  $phone  = $_POST['phone'];
  $address  = $_POST['address'];
  $id_role = $_POST['id_role'];

  //Enkripsi password
  $encrypt_pass = md5($password);

  include_once("app/model/crud.php");
  $crud  = new Crud();

  //Cek user
  $cek  = $crud->execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_owner WHERE username = '{$username}'");
  if ($cek->num_rows != 0) {
   $message = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' align='center'>
    Username sudah terdaftar!
   </div>";
  } else {
   //Menyimpan user baru
   $register = $crud->execute("INSERT INTO tbl_owner VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$encrypt_pass}', '{$fullname}', '{$gender}', '{$phone}', '{$address}', '{$id_role}')");

   if ($register) {
    $message = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' align='center'>
     Pendaftaran Sukses! Silahkan <a href='login.php'>Login</a>
    </div>";
   } else {
    $message = "<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissable' align='center'>
     Pendaftaran Gagal!
    </div>";
   }
  }
 }
 
 //Menampilkan Tampilan UI
 include 'app/view/header.php';
 include 'app/view/menu.php';
 include 'app/view/auth/register.php';
 include 'app/view/footer.php'; 
 ?>
```

end this is the crud class

```html
<?php 
 /**
  * crud class
  */
 class Crud 
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
         include('app/config/database.php');
         $this->db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
     }

     function execute($query)
     {
      $result = $this->db->query($query);
      return $result;
     }
 }
 ?>
```

please. Help me?

Comment: Can you try adding try and catch statements when you execute the query, and var_dump the $result?

Comment: how to create? sorry, i'm newbie.. :-D

Comment: I've tried and it still had no information at all

Comment: `try {
    $register = $crud->execute("INSERT INTO tbl_owner VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$encrypt_pass}', '{$fullname}', '{$gender}', '{$phone}', '{$address}', '{$id_role}')");
   } catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
   }`

Comment: Are you sure your code flow is working, first it should make an insert query then it would send query to this execute function, Can you echo the query and exit out there.

function execute($query)
     {
                echo $query;exit;
      $result = $this->db->query($query);
      return $result;
     }

Comment: i have tried. but, did not happen anything

Comment: Means your code didn't reach till execute statement. Time to debug each and every step.

Comment: OK. I try to check back in. thanks.

Comment: Switch to PDO instead of mysqli? than i can help you (:

Answer (score -1):

Please Check with your IF Condition, There was a error with `if (isset($POST['username'])` . Change that to

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {}
```

Else, print that Query in the View and copy that query to Database Query manager, then try that. Then you can find the error with this query clearly.

Comment: datatype of primary key is int. For `default` i use `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: So do not try to insert `NULL` in that point, just leave that

Comment: Use `$register = $crud->execute("INSERT INTO tbl_owner VALUES ('{$username}', '{$encrypt_pass}', '{$fullname}', '{$gender}', '{$phone}', '{$address}', '{$id_role}')");`

Comment: nothing happened... can you help me. this is my app https://github.com/oimtrust/paykoos

Comment: There was a error in your `IF CONDITION`. You have mentioned as `isset($POST['username'])`. Change to `isset($_POST['username'])'.
Change it to following code.

Comment: Just use this query format,
`$register = $crud->execute("INSERT INTO tbl_owner VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$encrypt_pass', '$fullname', '$gender', '$phone', '$address', '$id_role')");  `
You want to insert a value for Auto Increment also

Answer (score -1):

Try it....

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
```

Instead of

```
if (!empty($POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
```

Comment: @Oim Trust you are missing unserscore( _ ) in post method with if condition